# jquery ui datepicker adding custom column

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to take the out-of-the-box ui datepicker and repurpose it as a calendar based status display.

I'm having trouble trying to populate my additional column. This code updates the value just fine but the result is always the greatest week number, in this case week 13. I have stepped through this and can see week 1, week 2, etc. being applied, I just don't know how the make week 1 stick on week 1, and 2 on 2, and so on. Eventually, I'll add add an ajax function to populate those values with real percentages.

```
$('td.ui-datepicker-week-col').each(function (index) {
    var weekno = $(this).text();
    var pctValHTML = "<td id=pct-val-" + weekno + " class='pctVal'>" + weekno + "</th>";
    $("td.pctVal").replaceWith(pctValHTML);
});
```

How can I update my new column?

Here's my fiddle showing the current behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/mv5492/PuWWS/1/

Note that a refresh (click a day, get alert) wipes out the added column. I'm looking at that one separately.

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$("td.pctVal").replaceWith(pctValHTML);
```

Is selecting every single `td.pctVal` and replacing the HTML. This causes every `td.pctVal` to contain the value of the last week that's iterated over. You probably want something like this instead:

```
$(this)
    .closest('tr')            // find the common ancestor `tr`
    .find('td.pctVal')        // from there, find the correct `td.pctVal`
    .replaceWith(pctValHTML);
```

**Updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PuWWS/7/